# Jinja adds unnecessary double quotations when sending to data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to add backend support to my React project using Flask.

In my python file I'm trying to send information from my sqlite3 database:

```
@bp.route('/')
def index():
    #get_db() is a function defined elsewhere to connect to the database
    db = get_db()
    posts = db.execute(
        'SELECT """relevant fields"""'
        ' FROM """relevant columns"""'
        ' ORDER BY created DESC'
    ).fetchall()

    #thats to my knowledge the best solution to not return a sqlite3.Row object:
    info = []
    for row in rows:
        info.append(list(row))  

    return render_template('/index.html', info=json.dumps(info, default=str)) #default=str to handle date object
```

My relevant HTML in which I receive the `info` object:

```
<div id="root" data-info={{info}}></div>
```

And then I try to parse it and pass to my React app in my (*external*) js file:

```
const info = document.getElementById('root').dataset.info;
var allInfo = info ? JSON.parse(info) : null;
```

My problem is that in my HTML the `info` object somehow returns from `render_template` as a messed up junk (puts the string from `info` as weird attributes), I think because of an unnecessary addition of double quotation mark (viewed using chrome devtools):

```
<div id="root" data-info="[[1," "abc",="" "2021-01-25="" 14:13:02",="" 1,="" "user",="" "name=""]]=""></div>
```

Why does this happen? I tried adding pipes such as `|tojson` or `|safe` but they were of no help.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

---

Edit:

I've managed to at least receive everything in `data-info` by altering the python file:

```
@bp.route('/')
def index():
    #get_db() is a function defined elsewhere to connect to the database
    db = get_db()
    posts = db.execute(
        'SELECT """relevant fields"""'
        ' FROM """relevant columns"""'
        ' ORDER BY created DESC'
    ).fetchall()

    #thats to my knowledge the best solution to not return a sqlite3.Row object:
    info = ""
    for row in rows:
        info+=(str(list(row))) #replaced info from list to string  

    return render_template('/index.html', info) #removed the json dump
```

Now I managed to receive it as a non-friendly, non-json text:

```
<div id="root" data-info="[1, \u0027abc\u0027, datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 26, 7, 55, 9), 1, \u0027user\u0027, \u0027name\u0027]"></div>
```

Which gives me what I want, but now I need to regex it to properly digest it in my React app. I'm **sure** there's a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Pass to the `render_template` function usual dict:

```
return render_template('/index.html', info)
```

And in template use `tojson` filter twice, it has to help you:

```
<div id="root" data-info={{ info | tojson | tojson }}></div>
```

Output will be:

```
<div id="root" data-info="{\\"example\\": 1}"></div>
```

Comment: I'm using external JS, not a <script> tag, so to my knowledge this is my only way of transferring the object to this JS file.